# convert json object to XML in UWP

Tags: c#, json, xml, uwp, json-deserialization

I have a c# client written for uwp.

It has a REST API Client.

The Server code is this:

```
*API Controller*

[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<Services.Group> Get(Guid companyRef)
{
    return groupRepository.Get(companyRef);
}
```

The Model is this:

```
public class Group
{
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public Guid GroupRef { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Guid CompanyRef { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

My client is this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(Shared.URL);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(Shared.HeaderType));
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri + route + "?" + GeneralTags.COMPANY_REF + "=" + ApplicationObject.CompanyRef);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var objs = JArray.Parse(json); // parse as array  

ApplicationObject.GroupData = objs.Select(x => new Model.Group
{
    Description = (string)x[GeneralTags.DESCRIPTION],
    GroupRef = (Guid)shared.CheckForNulls(x[GeneralTags.GROUP_REF], typeof(Guid)),
    Name = (string)x[GeneralTags.NAME]
}).ToList();
```

However, I am  now replacing:

```
ApplicationObject.GroupData = objs.Select(x => new Model.Group
{
    Description = (string)x[GeneralTags.DESCRIPTION],
    GroupRef = (Guid)shared.CheckForNulls(x[GeneralTags.GROUP_REF], typeof(Guid)),
    Name = (string)x[GeneralTags.NAME]
}).ToList();
```

with this so the data is contained in an XML document instead:

```
var doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof( XmlDocument));
```

but i get an error of this:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
```

Whilst I understand what the error message is telling me I am unsure how to implement a fix/change

Answer (score 0):

You could try to deserialize the object into List and then serialize that List into XML.

Comment: Hi, this would be a 2 step process. I could achieve the same parsing the ApplicationObject.GroupData